# Android generate / get kml google earth file from coordinates

Tags: android, gps, kml, google-earth

Hi does anyone has a glue how to get a kml file out of a set of coordinates measure with an android device?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is generate a KML file, KML files are XML files, they are quite easy to write just like any text file. See https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference for documentation on the syntax.

Comment: thanks, I needed that. what is the difference to KMZ file (as well for Google earth)

Comment: From the Wikipedia page of KML (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language): "KML files are very often distributed in KMZ files, which are zipped files with a .kmz extension. These must be legacy (ZIP 2.0) compression compatible"; there is more information on the contents of the archive on that page, or even better, there: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives. You could have got it by searching for "kmz file" on Google.

Comment: I mamaged to generate a kmz file and load it to the google earth app with MIME type "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz". however embedded images are not shown there. why? the desktop version works fine.

Comment: I don't really understand your question; I think you should provide more details. Anyway, since what you are asking is different, you must create a different question.

Comment: Yeah ok, I ll do that. Or maybe I ll find some answers. I am happy creating a KMZ file